# Determine language in custom post type pages in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, multilingual

I'm trying to build a simple 2-language wordpress site,
I've managed until now with duplicating each page for the second language, and finding out the current language by looking up in the page's URI whether it has a "/en" in it.
Now I have a problem with the CPT pages. The URI will be theSiteURL/cptName/id so I cannot determine what language is the user coming from.
The language switcher is simple links which link to thesiteURL/ or theSiteURL/en/.
Is there any way to store the lang val on click there, or other way I cannot think about?

Thank you.

Comment: Which plugin have you used for that ?

Comment: No plugin. There are just 2 languages and few pages so I worked it out myself.

Comment: Why don't you give default permalink setting to them ?

Comment: to what? pls explain

Comment: In wordpress setting, change permalink setting.So your url will look something like this `URL/?CPT=id` when you use CPT.